# Why align-items-center doesn't work?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, web, bootstrap-4

justify-content-center works properly but align-items-center not

HTML code:

```
<div class="container h-100">
   <!--Another content-->
  <div class="footer bg-dark ">
        <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <span >&copy 2014 Keepsake. All rights reserved. Theme by 
         elemis</span>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
div.footer{
width: 100%;
height: 150px;
span{
    color:white;
}
}
```

Comment: it does work... but the `row` has no defined height so there is nothing to vertical center. Give the row a defined height and you'll see it work: https://www.codeply.com/go/7nHlTJOC1W

Answer (score -1):

Add `display: block` to your `div.footer` probably it will work.